# Error when trying to change borders and the position of an element in Java GUI

Tags: java, swing, awt

I'm trying to create a button using Java the changing of the position and the size of JButon isn;t working this way. I'm using setbounds for the size and the Borderlayout for the position. Can anyone show me how to change the size and the position of a Jbutton in the right way?

This is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.imageio.*;
public class Back extends JFrame{


    private JButton r;

    public Back(){


         super("title");
         setLayout(new FlowLayout());
         r=new JButton ("ROLL THE DICE");
         add(r,BorderLayout.SOUTH); 
         r.setBounds(100, 100, 20, 70);

         thehandler hand=new thehandler();//konstruktori i handler merr nje instance te Background
         r.addActionListener(hand);

    }
     private class thehandler implements ActionListener{

         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

         }
         }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

         Back  d = new Back() ;

         d.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         d.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.GREEN);
         d.setSize(700,500);

         d.setVisible(true);    


    }

}
```

Comment: Use a different Layout manager. BorderLayout.SOUTH will display the button at its preferred height and the width of the container (700 in your case). That said, It is rarely a good idea to try to set the absolute position of a component. But if you must, create a JPanel with a null manager, set the button's size , add the button to the panel, and then add the panel to the SOUTH of the frame.

Comment: Start by having a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html). Layouts make many decisions about how to layout a container based on their design. Most make use of `getPreferred/Minimum/MaximumSize` (and combinations of) to determine the best way to layout components. These values are generally calculated by the components themselves, for instance, `JButton` will be using the text, margins and border insets as a base for calculating it's preferred size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one way, but a very, very, **very** bad way.

You can use :

```
setLayout(null);
```

Instead of :

```
setLayout(new FlowLayout());
```

And you get what you want.

But, **I recommend you not to use this.** The drawback would be that you will  have to set the locations of all the components manually. I added this **just for your information**.

Comment: Ok thanks but any answer why doesn't BorderLayout.SOUTH doesn't work?Cause I want to use BorderLayout instead of absolute position.

Comment: Probably because you use `setLayout(new FlowLayout());` instead of `setLayout(new BorderLayout());`